# how can i get profit for today, last 7 days and last 30 days using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]I have a profit table in my database, when I retrieve data from database I need to filter profit according to date (for `today`, `last 7 days`, `last 30 days`).

In my controller, I tried,

```
$todayProfit = Profit::whereDate('created_at',today())->get();
return response()->json($todayProfit);
```

but it provides only 24 hours, but I need today profit.

when i retrieve data to last 30 days using,

```
$lastMonthProfit = Profit::whereDate('created_at',today()->subDay(30))->get();
return response()->json($lastMonthProfit );
```

it is not working for me,
how can I solve

Comment: Please share your table structure and sample data

Comment: The first query should work, since you basically perform a `where` on today's date, so it should give you all records of today. Your second query list only the records of exactly 30 days back. You probably need something `where date > today-30`, so look into the docs how to do that.

Comment: i have share my table with screenshot @Ersoy

Comment: today() function provide the within 24 hours data..but I need only within date like only profit regarding 7/6/2020 only when call today profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for calculating all in a single one could be;

```
SELECT 'Today' as date, sum(profit) as total FROM profits 
WHERE created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
UNION
SELECT 'Last 7 days', sum(profit) FROM profits 
WHERE created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
UNION
SELECT 'Last 30 days', sum(profit) FROM profits 
WHERE created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
UNION
SELECT 'All', sum(profit) from profits;
```

The query builder version;

```
return Profit::where('created_at', '>', DB::raw('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)'))
        ->select([DB::raw('"Today" as date'), DB::raw('sum(profit) as total')])
        ->union(
            Profit::where('created_at', '>', DB::raw('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)'))
                ->select([DB::raw('"Last 7 days"'), DB::raw('sum(profit) as total')])
        )
        ->union(
            Profit::where('created_at', '>', DB::raw('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)'))
                ->select([DB::raw('"Last 30 days"'), DB::raw('sum(profit) as total')])
        )
        ->union(
            Profit::select([DB::raw('"All"'), DB::raw('sum(profit) as total')])
        )
        ->get();
```

it prints something like these;

```
[
    {
        "date": "Today",
        "total": "50"
    },
    {
        "date": "Last 7 days",
        "total": "145"
    },
    {
        "date": "Last 30 days",
        "total": "360"
    },
    {
        "date": "All",
        "total": "695"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I used your code it also provides an error. In my code i use the $profit vaiable to equal your code and the print it using dd($profit) not provide json as your output

Comment: I have uploaded the error in question as a screen shot

Comment: I think this all codes are correct, but when i used this code always provide some errors. Please help me to solve this

Comment: @ShasikaMadhushan it is front end related error - you need to fix your front end components i think. The query and the method(query builder) works fine according to the your table structure. I think this front-end error is out of the scope of question, since the question is `how can i get profit for today, last 7 days and last 30 days`. I am not front-end guy. It is better to open another question to solve how to print json to front-end according to your requirements.

Comment: Sorry for the big mistake from me, Your code is correct and I could get an answer that I hope

Comment: i have some issue regarding total profit, i need combine it to code that you provided. total profit means summation of the profir column in profit table..how do it possible

Comment: @ShasikaMadhushan do you mean profit without time limit? Since the beginning?

Comment: your code consist today profit , last 7 days proft and last 30 days profit. I need another one to calculate total profit without time limit

Comment: $profit = DB::table("profits")->get()->sum("profit"); this is my code but i need this one also included to your code

Comment: @ShasikaMadhushan i will update, check it in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get only data of 30 days ago not from 30 days ago till now. To solve that problem maybe you should use `whereBetween`. Try this and let me know if it solves your problem.

```
$todayProfit = Profit::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfDay(), now()]);

$lastMonthProfit = Profit::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subMonth(), now()]);
```

Comment: Thank you...but I tried this and provide the error as a screenshot that I provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code get data to last `30 days` using,

```
$date = Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
$lastMonthProfit = Profit::where('created_at','>=',$date)->get();
return response()->json($lastMonthProfit );
```

last 7 days

```
$date = Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
$lastSevenDayProfit = Profit::where('created_at','>=',$date)->get();
return response()->json($lastSevenDayProfit );
```

today

```
$todayProfit = Profit::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
return response()->json($todayProfit,200);
```